Is there a way to return a default value of an object when the object is called?
First of all thanks for taking the time to read this.
Second I hope you can understand what I mean since I dont know how to objectively ask this.
I have an object (for example):
const object = { value1: "1", value2: "2", value3: "3" }
If I now use console.log(object) I want it to log the value of value1 instead of the object.
I know I can just use object.value1, but since I want to use it on larger objects it might get messy + it will make stuff easier for me.
I've search quite a bit online for the solution, but couldnt find anything.
All I was able to find: console.log(a.value1 || "1").
Which I dont want since value1 may be different + it defeats the whole purpose of what I want.

You could use a different value after ||, it's just a fallback for if the first value is "falsy". You could override toString on the object, or on the prototype if it's not an anonymous object, but doing so could cause unexpected behavior elsewhere based on variable usage.

console.log has its own way of representing objects, so if you do console.log(object) the result will even differ slightly between different environments. You could write your own console implementation and then you have full control. Is that really what you want though?

Im sorry, what I meant I want it that object returns the value of value1 everywhere (I used console.log() as an example), without needing to add the .value1 everywhere.

Why would you need this? How would it be possible to access any other property of object if that object evaluates to its value1 property? Like when you write object.value2, then object would evaluate to value1 and you would actually evaluate value1.value2... So you could never access any other property of that object... I don't get it.
